# Calculating Centripetal Acceleration of Sun about Galaxy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force, celestial-mechanics

This is a question from my Mechanics book:

Calculate the centripetal acceleration relative to the acceleration due to gravity of:

c) the Sun in its rotation about the center of the galaxy (the radius of the Sun's orbit about the center of the galaxy is $2.8 * 10^4$ LY and its orbital speed is 220 km/s)

My attempt at an answer: I convert the radius of orbit and orbital speed to meters. To get angular velocity, I then divide the orbital speed by the radius. To get centripetal acceleration, I square the angular velocity and multiply it by the radius. I then divide by $g = 9.8$ to get the centripetal acceleration relative to gravity.

The problem is, the figure I get is about $1.8 * 10^{-11}$, whereas the book's answer is $1.5*10^{-12}$. I tried to use the Sun's gravity instead (274, right?) and got about $6.437 *10^{-13}$. Neither answer matches the book's, and I have no clue how they got it.

I was wondering if there were any flaws in reasoning I was making here, or if the book's answer is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome Bookie, could you please, if you are intending to post any more questions, use mathjax in your post. It gives you a better chance of an answer. Thanks

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. How do I use/where would I learn mathjax?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: No problem, this is the main mathjax reference    http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't seem to work out how the book got that answer either and my conclusion would be that the answer is wrong or that the question is poorly worded/explained. I also computed about $1.8(6)*10^{-11}$ but did notice some lack of optimisation in your approach...

Note that the centripetal acceleration can be calculated using the angular velocity and radius of orbit as you did:

$a = rw^2 $

note that $w = v/r$ where $v$ is the linear velocity. Thus the centripetal acceleration can be written:

$a = r(v^2/r^2) = v^2/r$

hence there was no need to convert to angular velocity.

All the best